# Eiffel: Call use obsolete feature. Call to feature `to_string_8': Use `name_32' instead

Tags: eiffel, eiffel-studio-18

I have a warning I cannot get rid of neither understand:

> Eiffel: Call use obsolete feature. Call to feature `to_string_8': Use 'name_32' instead

`item_prototype` is a DB_SERVICE where I redefine `out`

```
if attached {APP_CONFIGURATION}.application_instance.selected_entity_primary_key ({SIT_UTIL}.class_name_lowercase ({like item_prototype})) as l_pk then
```

[image]
[image]

One more point is that I **wasn't able to copy the warning msg to my clipboard**, how do I do that? if there is a way into EiffelStudio.

Comment: I suggest asking the second question separately because it is unrelated to the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the feature `{SIT_UTIL}.class_name_lowercase` takes an argument of type `STRING`, but the current code supplies type `TYPE [...]` — the type of `{like item_prototype}`. There is a conversion feature `to_string_8` in the class `TYPE`, but it is obsolete, that's why you get a warning.

Either the signature of the feature `class_name_lowercase` has to be changed to accept `TYPE` instead of `STRING`, or the argument should be of the form `({like item_prototype}).name_32.as_string_8`.

In order to support Unicode identifiers, it's better to change the signature of `class_name_lowercase` anyway, so that it accepts `STRING_32`, and to pass `({like item_prototype}).name_32`.

Comment: Correct thx! I had to change `{SIT_UTIL}.class_name_lowercase ({like item_prototype})` to `{SIT_UTIL}.class_name_lowercase (({like item_prototype}).out)` and solved my case. My class_name_lowercase was already getting a STRING as argument